# Large result sets with Hibernate and MaxDB

Tags: database, hibernate, relational-database, maxdb

I need to synchronize a large XML file (containing 6 million records sorted by ID) against a SAP MaxDB database table.

This is my present strategy:

- read XML object from file and convert to Java bean
- load object with the same primary key from database (see below)
- if object does not exist, insert object
- if object exists and is changed, update object
- at the end of the process, scan the database table for (deleted) objects that are not contained in the file

For efficiency reasons, the "load database object" method keeps a cache of the next 1000 records and issues statements to load the next bunch of objects. It works like this:

```
List<?> objects = (List<?>)transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
  public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
    ht.setMaxResults(BUNCH_SIZE);
    ht.setFetchSize(BUNCH_SIZE);
    List<?> objects = ht.find("FROM " + simpleName + " WHERE " +
      primaryKeyName + " >= ? ORDER BY " + primaryKeyName, primaryValue);
    return objects;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, for some constant values of BUNCH_SIZE (10,000) I get a SQL exception "result table space exhausted".

- How can I better optimize the process?
- How can I avoid the SQL exception / the bunch size problem?

The code that saves the changed objects is the following:

```
if (prevObject == null) {
  ht.execute(new HibernateCallback(){
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
    throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      session.save(saveObject);
      session.flush();
      session.evict(saveObject);
      return null;
    }
  });
  newObjects++;
} else {
  List<String> changes = ObjectUtil.getChangedProperties(prevObject, currentObject);
  if (hasImportantChanges(changes)) {
    changedObjects++;
    ht.merge(currentObject);
  } else
    unchangedObjects++;
  }
}
```

While this code works in principle, it produces masses of database log entries (we are talking about more than 50 GB of log backups) if there are a lot of new or changed objects in the source file.

- Can I improve this code by using a lower transaction isolation level?
- Can I reduce the amount of database log data written?
- Maybe there is a problem with the database configuration?

I am very grateful for any help. Thanks a lot, Matthias

Comment: if (flushCounter >= 50) { ht.flush(); ht.clear(); flushCounter = 0; } after ht.merge() does not really help ;-)